# Devexpress NavigationBar Item Onclick to load Grid into GridControl

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I am a newbie to `devexpress`, I really need help on how to manage `NavBarControl` item. When Navbar item `onclick` event is fired I want to load a GridView into `gridControl`.

For example. Let say I have two item/link in Group A which are **link 1** and **link 2**, when Group A - **Link 1** is clicked I want to load `gridview1` into `gridControl1` and if **Link 2** is clicked load `gridView2` to gridControl

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far :) Is your problem to get the click response on a link or to load a different gridView in your Control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When Navbar item onclick event is fired I want to load a GridView into gridControl.

Take a look at the [NavBarControl.LinkClicked](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraNavBarNavBarControl_LinkClickedtopic) event. You can handle this event as follows(use the e.Link property to detect the specific link):

```
navBarControl1.LinkClicked += navBarControl1_LinkClicked;
//...
void navBarControl1_LinkClicked(object sender, NavBarLinkEventArgs e) {
    if(e.Link.Item == navBarItem1)
        gridControl1.MainView = gridView1;
    if(e.Link.Item == navBarItem2)
        gridControl1.MainView = cardView1;
}
```

Or you can handle the corresponding [NavBarItem.LinkClicked](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraNavBarNavBarItem_LinkClickedtopic) event for the specific items:

```
navBarItem1.LinkClicked += navBarItem1_LinkClicked;
navBarItem2.LinkClicked += navBarItem2_LinkClicked;
//...
void navBarItem1_LinkClicked(object sender, NavBarLinkEventArgs e) {
    gridControl1.MainView = gridView1;
}
void navBarItem2_LinkClicked(object sender, NavBarLinkEventArgs e) {
    gridControl1.MainView = cardView1;
}
```